# Ruby on Rails Domain/Site Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns

What is the best way to structure a rails application on the web? I know quite a few sites are now shifting and putting their rails app on company.com and putting their official website on companyhq.com or companyapp.com. Is that a good way to do things?

I was hoping for having an all in one company.com which is running on rails and that app also contains the website. But I am guessing if something goes wrong or for maintenance, both the app and the website will be unavailable.

Or a third option is to have the website on www.company.com and have the app running on manage.company.com. But would rails running on a subdomain limit its capabilities in any way?

To prevent any confusion - by "website" I am referring to the basic external pages - Home, Contact Us etc. and "app" is a rails production application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this does not really have anything to do with rails. it's up to your webserver to map your url structure (paths subdomains). this could be multiple rails apps, a mixture of rails and other stuff like php or whatever you are running, or static sites.